# proving to see that a normal subgroup is equal to a subgroup if one of the subgroup is the identity.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Can anyone check my attempt on the question which i have prosed hours ago .

Question:

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H◁G$ a normal subgroup. Prove that $|G/H|=|G|$ if and only if $H=\{e\}$.

My attempt:

Let $G$ be an finite group. Now we are to show that $|G/H|=|G|$ if $|H|=\{e\}$. To prove that $H$ is the unit element. That is $H=eH$ and $gH\upvarepsilon|G/H|$ holds that $eH * gH =(eg)H = gH$ and $gH * eH = (ge)H = gH$. Now we are to established that all the element $gH\upvarepsilon |G/H|$ has inverse, we show $g$ inverse element of $H$ and $G=H$. Since $gH(g^{-1})H = (g g^{-1})H = eH = H$ and $(g^{-1})HgH = (g^{-1}g)H = eH = H$ completing the proof. –

Comment: why don't you look to size of group $\frac{G}{H}$?

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. Also, if you are going to be a regular here, please learn something about how to format mathematics on this site. There are links under "Help".

Comment: [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I have tried to format your post. I am not sure what you mean by `\upvarepsilon`.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Since $H$ is a normal subgroup, $\frac{G}{H}$ is a group. Thus $|\frac{G}{H}|=\frac{|G|}{|H|}$.

Comment: So that mean i take all the element and divide them?

Comment: Since $H$ is a normal subgroup, you can do it

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $G/H= \{ gH \mid g \in G\}$. Clearly, $|G/H| \leq |H|$ with equality if and only if $gH \neq g'H$ when $g \neq g' \in G$. In particular, for all $g \in G \backslash \{e\}$, $gH \neq eH=H$, that is $g \notin H$. Therefore, $H \subset \{e\}$. Now $H$ is a subgroup, hence $H=\{e\}$.